# Emacs `captain-mode` auto-capitalization in comment

Tags: comment, capitalization

I installed `captain-mode`, and it worked as expected in org/text modes, but not so quite in programming modes' comment lines.

The problem is it can auto-capitalize the first word from the second sentence onwards, but not the first word in the first sentence.

```
// first sentence. Second sentence.
```

As you can see, `first` is not capitalized by the captain mode, but the `Second` is. Does anyone know what I may have done wrong?

here is my configuration related to this mode.

```lisp
(global-captain-mode t)
;; don't capitalize in programming modes. 
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     (setq captain-predicate
           (lambda () (nth 8 (syntax-ppss (point)))))))
;; Or for text modes, work all the time:
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq captain-predicate (lambda () t))))
;; Or don't work in source blocks in Org-mode:
(add-hook
 'org-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (setq captain-predicate
         (lambda () (not (org-in-src-block-p))))))
(setq sentence-end-double-space nil)
```

Comment: Please do not post the same comment in StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Please pick one and delete the other. Thx. :) just kidding. I deleted the other one, along with your comment.